WPF, Grid, UserControl with two items
For settings, I frequently use  with two columns: TextBlock for header/label and TextBox for value. It could be done in , but I want to have columns aligned.
E.g.
  <TextBlock Text="Server" Grid.Row="0"/>
  <TextBox Name="uiFtpServer" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1"/>

I want to create UserControl for this. I almost did it :) Grid.Children contains TextBlock, but it is not displayed (Height=Width=0).
<local:GridedTBox x:Name="uiFtpServer" Label="Server" Grid.Row="0"/>
and
Public Class GridedTBox
    Inherits TextBox
    ' making GridedTBox inherited from TextBox, I have all TextBox properties available on GridedTBox level

    Private _Label As New TextBlock

    Public Property Label As String
        Get
            Return _Label.Text
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            _Label.Text = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Overrides Sub OnApplyTemplate()

        Dim gridek As Grid = TryCast(Me.VisualParent, Grid)
        If gridek Is Nothing Then Return

        gridek.Children.Add(_Label)
        ' _Label is added, but height=NaN, desiredsize=0,0, actualwidht=0, etc.

        If Grid.GetColumn(Me) > 0 Then
            Grid.SetColumn(_Label, Grid.GetColumn(Me) - 1)
        Else
            Grid.SetColumn(Me, 1)
            Grid.SetColumn(_Label, 0)
        End If

        _Label.ApplyTemplate()
        MyBase.OnApplyTemplate()

        ' still _Label has height=NaN, desiredsize=0,0, actualwidht=0, etc.
        ' now, debugging says that Grid.Columns has proper values (i.e. 1 for TextBox, 0 for TextBlock)
        ' but TextBox on screen is in column 0, so something changes it after this OnApplyTemplate

    End Sub
End Class

Questions: what am I doing wrong? Should I use another EventHandler?

You're not really creating a "user control". Wrapping the TextBlock and TextBox in a horizontal StackPanel or Grid; all within a UserControl as its "Content" would qualify as a "user control". (Controls "collapse" if they're "empty" and don't have a default size). You can always "prime" .Text properties while testing to detect those types of issues (when they're empty).

Ok, maybe it is not real UserControl. But question is - why TextBlock has all sizes 0, and what can I do to show this TextBlock?

Please provide the XAML for your user control

Add specific "Width" and "Height" values when confounded by "star" and "Auto" columns and rows; or Stretch, Left, Right, Top, and Bottom "alignments". Or collapsed StackPanels.
